# A Line break occurring between Label and custom component

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-design-system, html, slds

Below is the screenshot, where the Customer and Division are not aligned. But anyhow the bill to and Ship to are aligned

[image]

This is my HTML code, where i am using the same code for both the elements

```
fieldset class="slds-form-element slds-form-element_compound">
            <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                <div class="slds-form-element__row">
                <div class="slds-size_1-of-2">                       
                    <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="input-01">Customer</label>                       
                        <c-lookup sobject-name="Account"
                        title="Name"
                        subtitle="AccountNumber"
                        onselected={handleAccountLookup}
                        placeholder="Search Salon..."
                        icon-name="standard:account">
                        </c-lookup>
                </div>
                <div class="slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <div class="slds-form-element">
                    <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="input-02">Division</label>
                    
                    <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                        <select class="slds-select">
                            <template for:each={divisionrecords} for:item="division">
                                <option key={division.Division__c} value={division.Division__c}>{division.Division__c}</option>
                            </template>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>    
                </fieldset>


                <fieldset class="slds-form-element slds-form-element_compound">
                    <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                        <div class="slds-form-element__row">
                        <div class="slds-size_1-of-2">
                            <div class="slds-form-element">
                            <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="input-01">Bill To</label>
                            <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                                <select class="slds-select">
                                    <template for:each={billtobillrecords} for:item="billtobill">
                                        <option key={billtobill.Name} value={billtobill.Name}>{billtobill.Name}</option>
                                    </template>
                                </select> 
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="slds-size_1-of-2">
                            <div class="slds-form-element">
                            <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="input-02">Ship To</label>
                            <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                                <select class="slds-select">
                                    <template for:each={shiptorecords} for:item="shipto">
                                        <option key={shipto.Name} value={shipto.Name}>{shipto.Name}</option>
                                    </template>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>    
                        </fieldset>
```

Can anyone please let me know the reason, right now i am just adding a line break to Division so that they both come into alignment.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: c-lookup cmp need to be wrap with   ` <div class="slds-form-element__control">` , if i takeout your c-lookup component and add select base component alignment works prefect.

Comment: @sdandamud1 Can you please elaborate a little more i am not getting it.  <div class="slds-form-element__control"> is wrapped under c-lookup component